# How to use getChildren and getData method together in node-zookeeper-client using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-zookeeper

I'm new to Node.js. I'm trying to use node-zookeeper-client from npm(Github link - https://github.com/alexguan/node-zookeeper-client)

I wanted to understand how to use getChildren and getData method available in this library together.(I understand these uses callbacks)

The aim is, to iterate through all the children of a given path and get the data of all children and print it out sychronously before going to next children.

```
var zookeeper = require('node-zookeeper-client');
var client = zookeeper.createClient('localhost:2181');
var path =  "/Services/Apache";
var tmpChildren = [];

function getChildren(client,path){

console.log('path value received is..', path );
client.getChildren(path, function (error, children, stats) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.stack);
        return;
    }

    console.log('Children are: %s', children);
    tmpChildren = String(children).split(",");
    var newPath="";

   for(var i=0; i < tmpChildren.length ; i++)
   {
      newPath = path+'/'+tmpChildren[i];
      console.log('children is %s',tmpChildren[i]);
      var str = client.getData(newPath, function(error,data){
             if (error) {
              return error.stack; 
          }
             return data ? data.toString() : undefined;

      });
      console.log('Node: %s has DATA: %s', newPath, str);
  }

}

);

}

client.once('connected', function () 
    {
    console.log('Connected to the server.');
    getChildren(client,path);


});

client.connect();
```

The above piece of code is what I have. The output is as follows

```
Connected to the server.
path value received is.. /Services/Apache
Children are: Instance4,Instance3,Instance2,Instance1
children is Instance4
Node: /Services/Apache/Instance4 has DATA: undefined
children is Instance3
Node: /Services/Apache/Instance3 has DATA: undefined
children is Instance2
Node: /Services/Apache/Instance2 has DATA: undefined
children is Instance1
Node: /Services/Apache/Instance1 has DATA: undefined
```

If you see the DATA it's getting printed as undefined. I expect the correct data for each
individual child node to be printed instead of undefined.

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

PS: The data gets printed inside the function of *client.getData()*, but not getting assigned to variable str.

Answer (score 0):

`getData` is an asynchronous function, you will not be able to return the value back to the caller. It will always be undefined since the callback is invoked in a different stack in a later time.

To print out the data, you need to put `console.log` statement inside of the getData callback function. e.g.

```
  client.getData(newPath, function(error,data){
      if (error) {
          console.log(error.stack); 
          return;
      }

      console.log('Node: %s has DATA: %s', newPath, data ? data.toString() : '');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex. But is there any other way I can get the value data outside getData method? I want to the *data* to be available outside getData method so that I an form JSON with the node's data.